# How to use the `tax[13]-eq-dc` regex in a Bash loop?

Tags: bash, regex

The following regex `tax[13]-eq-dc` represents two servers, tax1-eq-dc and tax3-eq-dc.
I'm trying to find a way to use it in a Bash do loop, but can't just get the correct syntax.

E.g., the following is wrong:

```
$ for i in tax[13]-eq-dc; do ping -c3 $i; done
ping: unknown host tax[13]-eq-dc
```

Any ideas what would be the correct syntax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tax[13]-eq-dc` may look like a regex but in your code Bash does not treat it as such. Even if it did, a regex is to match *something*. What do you want to match?

Bash treats your `tax[13]-eq-dc` as a [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html) (globbing) pattern. It's not a regex, although `[13]` in it is somewhat similar to `[13]` in regular expressions. Like regex, filename expansion is also designed to match something; it's designed to match filenames.

It so happens in your current working directory there are no files with names matching the pattern, so the string is not expanded and ultimately `ping` gets `tax[13]-eq-dc` as an argument. If you had a file named `tax1-eq-dc` or a file named `tax3-eq-dc`, then the pattern would be expanded to one or two words, to all the matching names of *existing* files, and you would run one or two `ping`s trying to ping `tax1-eq-dc` or `tax3-eq-dc` or both.

Relying on existence of files makes no sense here. Most likely you do not want to match filenames. You probably want a [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html): `tax{1,3}-eq-dc`. This expands to two separate words: `tax1-eq-dc` and `tax3-eq-dc`, and it's a purely textual expansion that has nothing to do with files.

The filename expansion is a portable feature, the brace expansion is not.

```
for i in tax{1,3}-eq-dc; do ping -c3 "$i"; done
```

Comment: tax[13]-eq-dc are two servers (hence the `ping`s), tax1-eq-dc and tax3-eq-dc

Comment: @boardrider If you had a file containing a list of servers, you could use the regexp with `grep` to filter it to the servers that match that pattern. `for i in $(grep 'tax[13]-eq-dc' servers.txt)`

Comment: It should be noted, that in the final proposed use it's also not a regex (for all the reasons stated). I'm just clarifying because an inexperienced user may think that the brace expansion is a regex feature.

Answer (score 3):

I wonder why you want to use regex, when your code does not require it:

`for i in 1 3; do ping -c3 tax${i}-eq-dc; done`

Indeed you can replace `1 3` with a brace expansion if more numbers are needed, but that's not the case in you question.